# iCloud Drive files have 2x Size on Disk

Tags: macos, icloud, ssd, disk-space

All all of my files that I download locally from iCloud Drive using "Download now", show locally as having 2x a size on disk than the actual file size...

Whether it's a photo or a large encrypted file, everything is using 2x the expected disk space. Any idea why?

**790MB Zip using 1.6GB:**

[image]

**11GB encrypted image using 22GB:**

[image]

**1.2MB photo using 2.5MB:**

[image]

UPDATE: strangely the 10GB image is now showing normally, but the other two examples are still 2x.

UPDATE2: only seems to happen on Monterey.

Comment: Are you using Time Machine?

Comment: @hawk nope I'm not